# How to programmatically check if microphone is used or not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, audio-recording

How to programmatically check if microphone is used or not on iPhone.
Since I want to check if Voice Memo is recording or not, is there the way to check this programmatically

Comment: Are you wanting to know if a headset is plugged in and it has a microphone?  There is a microphone built in to the iPhone on the bottom.

Comment: @bbarnhart I just want to check if VoiceMemo application is recording or not. That's why I want to check if the microphone is used or not

Comment: You can not check to see if Voice Memos or any other app is running from another app.  Are you wanting to to use the microphone from your app and trying to determine if it's available?

Comment: @bbarnhart, while I 'm recording using VoiceMemo, if I extract audio using AVAssetExportSession. VoiceMemo will stop recording automatically. So I want to detect if the microphone is being used or not. If it is being used, I will run my audio-extraction code later